# Powershell - replace line in .txt if condition is met

Tags: powershell

i'm quite new to scripting (few weeks) and would be happy about your help.
I've a log-file (.txt) which needs to be changed.

The content is always the same:

```
    random text
    random text
    successfull
    error

    random text
    random text
    random text
    error

    ...
```

I would like to remove the line containing the word "error", but only if the line above contains the word "successfull".

So far I managed to get all the matching strings out of the File and am able to replace them, but I lose the rest of the text in the process:

`get-content "D:\test.txt" | select-string -pattern "error" -context 1,0 | Where-Object {"$_" -match "successfull" } | %{$_ -replace "error.*"} | Out-File "D:\result.txt"`

I would really appreciate your help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some conditional logic (`if` statements) to achieve the goal:

```
$successful = $false
Get-Content d:\test.txt | Foreach-Object {
    if ($_ -match "successfull") {
        $successful = $true
        $_
    }
    elseif ($_ -match "error" -and $successful) {
       $successful = $false
    }
    else {
        $_
        $successful = $false
    }
}
```

Since we are piping the `Get-Content` result into `Foreach-Object`, `$_` becomes the current line being processed (each line is processed one by one). If a line contains `successfull`, then we mark `$successful` as `$true` and still output that line (`$_`). If the line contains `error`, then we will only output it if `$successful` is `$false`. Anytime we reach a line that does not contain `succcesfull`, we mark `$successful` as `$false`.

No deletion is actually occurring as it is merely not displaying `error` lines when the conditions are met.

Comment: Thanks al lot! :) Worked perfectly!

Comment: I'm still trying to understand how these statements work.
So first the trigger is set to false, until a line is found matching the word "successful".
Then the trigger is set to true. With $_ afterwards and the elseif statement the next line is checked for the word "error"? Where is the command to delete the line containing "error" if thes statements are true?
Thats what i'm struggling with to understand.

Comment: @ziotron, I added some explanation. Let me know if that clears it up

Comment: thx a lot :) Got it now, after your explanation. i also broke the code to see the different results to understand it